# How to make a Template class a friend of a class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

Consider the following partial code:

```cpp
namespace Util {
    template <class T>
    class SimpleSingleton
    {
    public:
        static T& getOne() {
            if (instance == NULL)
                instance = new T();
            return *instance;
        }
    private:
        static T* instance;
        // ...
    };
    T *Singleton<T>::instance = NULL;
}
class A
{
    friend class Util::Singleton<A>;
    //...
private:
    A() {};
    //...
};
typedef Util::Singleton<A> SingletonA;

void main()
{
    A a = SingletonA::Instance(); // c2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is the Singleton class made?

Comment: The short answer to "what am I doing wrong?" is: "using a singleton (at all)".

Comment: Why's that, @JerryCoffin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
A a = SingletonA::Instance();
```

to

```
A& a = SingletonA::Instance();
```

As written, the code tries to copy the object, but the copy constructor is private.

Comment: Just a minor note of clarity in case it is not immediately obvious what is stated here. The copy constructor is inaccessible from the perspective of the main function (from which the copy is attempted) since main is not a friend of A. The copy does not happen inside of the Singleton class, but if it did, there would not be an issue (with accessibility--there certainly would be irony in the design of a singleton class that itself creates copies).